# Accessing a randomly-assigned object

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, subclass, superclass

Given the following:

```
class ClassA

class ClassA1 extends ClassA
class ClassA2 extends ClassA
class ClassA3 extends ClassA

ClassA1 a1 = new ClassA1()
ClassA2 a2 = new ClassA2()
ClassA3 a3 = new ClassA3()

ClassA a = either a1, a2, or a3 (programmed to be randomly chosen by JVM)
```

If the reference to the subclass object (either 'a1', 'a2', or 'a3') is only assigned to the superclass reference variable 'a' at runtime, how can I write an 'if' statement that implements: if 'a' refers to a1, access a specified field of a1 (which is not inherited from a)? Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator and casting.

```
if (a instanceof ClassA1) {
    ((ClassA1) a).someMethodThatsOnlyInA1();
}
```

Comment: Though it should be said that using this is a mark of bad design.

Comment: Tbh, I can imagine real-world situations of this scenario, cfr. proxy subclasses with different implementation libraries...

Comment: Yes, this kind of code certainly exists in the real world.  I know this, because I happen to inhabit the real world.  Sometimes, you have to choose between pointing at the design of a piece of software and saying "this is bad design", and getting on and doing your actual job.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic for letting me know. Is there a way to achieve this with better design?

Comment: @mlm To answer that you'll have to explain your project - what the classes represent, why you need to call a subclass-specific method after you have just randomly picked an object, and if there are any constraints on this (e.g. if this is homework and there are things you are not allowed to do).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the instanceof operator.

```
if(a instanceof ClassA1) { ... }
```

Or you can use the isAssignableFrom method of the Class<> type.

```
if(ClassA1.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass())) { ... }
```

Both ways seem to do the same, however with instancof you should know the type at compile time, with isAssignableFrom you could check types dynamically at runtime, p.e.:

```
 if(a1.getClass().isAssignableFrom(a2.getClass())) { ... }
```

The last example cannot be written with the instanceof operator.

Though be aware for NullPointerExceptions because getClass() is a method!